# bs4 : insert new tag in a tag according to a specific attribute

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

After some research, I can't find adequate solutions: For example, i want to insert the tag 'b' inside a tag 'a' when 'id=2'  :

```
<?xml version"1.0 encoding="utf-8?>
<a id=1>
    <a id =2>
    </a>
</a>
```

I'm thinking about something like : `soup.a.has_key('2').append(b)`
but it doesn't work...
Some help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
s="""
<a id=1>
    <a id =2>
    </a>
</a>
"""

soup = bs(s)
nt = soup.new_tag('b')
soup.find(id="2").append(nt)
```

First a new `<b>` tag is created using `new_tag()`, the tag with `id="2"` is found with `find()` and the new tag is appended with `append()`.